# how to remove WINDOW OS from another drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

Here I have two OS in my laptop one Window 10 in C: drive and second is Window 7 in F: drive. When I start my laptop it ask select one OS. So how to remove Window 7 in my laptop without format my F:drive ?

Comment: So you only want to have Windows 10 on your computer?

Comment: yes @MorrisIriga

Comment: What you need to do is delete the volume with Windows 7 on it then extend the volume with Windows 10 to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove Windows 7's boot entry, and its system files

Removing boot entry:

1. Win key + R
2. msconfig, hit enter
3. Boot tab
4. Select Windows 7, delete

Then deleting the `Windows` directory in your `F:` drive should get back the space Windows 7 was taking up without reformatting

Answer (score -1):

You could follow my instructions to solve your issue:

1. Right-click on "My Computer" and choose "Properties"
2. From the left menu, choose "Advanced System Settings"
3. From the Windows "System Properties," choose "Settings" default operating
4. In "System," choose your Windows 10 as default boot and un-check "Time" to display list of operating systems

Comment: thanks @ Khoibm Your idea is good But I want remove Window 7 from my laptop.

Comment: @MayankVadiya: Neither answer removes Windows 7 from your laptop.